# Caption numbering missing in beamer class when adding subfig package

Tags: beamer, numbering, captions, subfloats, debian

I am having a problem with the beamer class and subfig package. Once I add the subfig package (for subfloats) the numbering of all my captions disappear. Please see the following minimial working example, where I included \usepackage{subfig} in line 13. Commenting the line out results in correct numbering. Thank you for any help!

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, .....
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

% subfloats
\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
   \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{figures/fig.pdf}
   \caption{Test caption}
  \end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please get rid of everything in your code that isn't relevant to your question; see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Okay, sorry, I edited the example, much shorter indeed ;) Thanks.

Comment: The caption number is typeset as expected in the output I get from your code (to which I only added the `demo` class option). Is your TeX distribution up to date?

Comment: Jubobs, thank you for checking! I obtained tex-live via apt-get standard repositories. $tex --version$ outputs $TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
kpathsea version 5.0.0$ so I guess the public repository is not up to date?

Comment: I'm not on Debian myself, but people seem to routinely experience similar problems with the TeX Live Debian distro. Wait for someone familiar with Debian for a definitive answer.

Comment: Update to the latest stable release of Debian. It ships TeXlive 2012, which is fairly recent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as most probably caused by outdated package version